# vsCode and Excel macros and .bas file extension association

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-code

I got tired of using the default VBA editor to create/modify MS Excel macros. And so, decided to try using the vsCode editor.  In the application marketplace there is a package named VBA - Visual Basic for Applications support for vsCode. This package had the most downloads and stars for the very limited number of VBA packages that are available in the marketplace.
The learning curve for VBA is somewhat steep, but it definitely allows for using vsCode to create and edit macros that get exported into Excel. Once installed, this package adds features to the vsCode Explorer.

In a nutshell, to use this package, first create an empty folder.  Open vsCode in this folder and then run the Bootstrap XVBA Config to populate a workspace in this folder. Add an Excel file to this folder.  Then use the VBA package features to create XML & macros modules that get exported to the Excel file.

This question involves using vsCode with .bas files.  I am unable to use vsCode's very useful Autocomplete and IntelliSense features when editing the .bas files.  So, what is the .json code that is needed in order to use vsCode's full editing features with .bas files?

Answer (score -1):

Since I was unable to find any similar questions or answers to my original question, I spend considerable effort in answering this question myself.

The vsCode editor has evolved over the years and there are multiple ways of accomplishing the same thing using vsCode.  I am old school and normally edit and update my custom vsCode User settings.json file directly.

The following line of code was added to the User settings.json file. This code enabled the full editing features of vsCode with .bas files.

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.bas": "vb"
    }
```

[image]